# ¿Cómo cargar un archivo con LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Bueno, hace un tiempo pregunté cómo se podía subir información de un archivo CSV desde PHP a MYSQL y lo logré hacer con CURL, pero la desventaja es que, al ser más de 10 000 registros se tarda mucho al hacer la verificación en la bd, por ello investigue y encontré que se puede hacer más rápido con la función LOAD DATA INFILE.

El problema es que ya ejecute mi sintaxis de código, pero no me hace la inserción en la base, alguien me puede apoyar revisando mi código? Desde ya se los agradezco.

```
   <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

/* Hace el llamado a la conexion a la BD */
require "../../APIs/conexion.php";

/* URL desde dónde se hará la descarga del archivo en formato excel .csv */
$url =  "http://omawww.sat.gob.mx/cifras_sat/Documents/Listado_Completo_69-B.csv";

/* Inicializa la función para obtener el archivo de la URL */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Decarga el documento y lo nombra como "listasNegras.csv" */
$fp = fopen("listasNegras.csv", "w");

/* Devuelve el resultado de la transferencia como string */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

/* Ejecuta la descarga del archivo desde la URL */
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM catContribuyentes";

try
{
    if(file_exists('listasNegras.csv'))
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql)) == 0)
        {
            $sql1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'listasNegras.csv'
                            INTO TABLE catContribuyentes
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                            IGNORE 3 LINES
                            (noContri, rfcContri, nombreContri, situacionContri, numFecContri, publicacionContri, numFecContriP, pubDOFContri, pubDesvContri, numFecDesvContri, publicacionDOFDes, numFecDefi, punlicacionDefi, publicacionDOFDef, numFecSentFav, pubSentSATFav, numFecSentFavD, pubDOFSentFav)";

            if(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql1))
            {
                echo "Insertados correctamente";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error al insertar archivos\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sql1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'listasNegras.csv'
                            REPLACE INTO TABLE catContribuyentes
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                            IGNORE 3 LINES
                            (noContri, rfcContri, nombreContri, situacionContri, numFecContri, publicacionContri, numFecContriP, pubDOFContri, pubDesvContri, numFecDesvContri, publicacionDOFDes, numFecDefi, punlicacionDefi, publicacionDOFDef, numFecSentFav, pubSentSATFav, numFecSentFavD, pubDOFSentFav)";

            if(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql1))
            {
                echo "Actualizado correctamente";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error al actualizar archivos\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error al cargar los datos: ", $e.getMessage(), '\n';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sale algún mensaje de error en los logs?

Answer (score 0):

Trata de cambiar esta parte **LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ** por  esta otra ** LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'**

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de como y porque la solución que propones soluciona el problema que se plantea, te invito a revisar [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y como no también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Adelante y gracias por tu aporte ;)

Comment: Gracias Actualice mi comentario con una mejor respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas que ocurran los puedes ver con el comando de MySQL `SHOW WARNINGS`.

Desde php puedes hacerlo con la función `mysqli_get_warnings()`:

```
if(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql1)){
   echo "Actualizado correctamente";
}else{
   echo "Error al actualizar archivos\n";
   if(mysqli_warning_count($conectar)) {
      $e = mysqli_get_warnings($conectar);
      while($e->next())
         echo "Warning: $e->errno: $e->message\n";
   }
}
```